# Creating circular symmetrical designs in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, shapes

I was wondering how to create these kind of circular repeating shapes in Adobe Illustrator. I searched the internet for a guide on creating these shapes but couldn't find anything.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Oumaima, welcome to GDSE. Unfortunately this is a Q&A site, not a tutorial site. However, if you can edit your question to tell us what you have tried and make your question more specific, we may be able to help you. Feel free to take a [tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) to get started.

Comment: Search for "mandala pattern Illustrator tutorial" on google. There are lots.

Comment: 'Lace Pattern' is a good search term too.

Answer (score 5):

One easy way is to use a transform effect...

1. Draw a circle and a line to use as a guide. (The line isn't all that important; it's just easy to see the rotation in this example and handy as a guide. The circle is important to get the correct rotation from the transform effect though).

[image]

2. Group the circle and the line and add a transform effect (*Effect → Distort & Transform → Transform...*) to *the group*. Set a number of copies and the correct rotation angle for the number of copies (tip: you can do math in the input, so put in "360/[number-of-copies]").

[image]

3. Draw inside the group. You can draw anywhere in the circle, you don't need to work within a single segment; everything will be rotated around the circle.

[image]

4. Hide your guide layers (don't delete the circle, it's needed for the transform effect; just make sure it isn't visible)...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The basic tool for all this in Illustrator is Object > Transform > Rotate > Copy. Type the rotation angle to be an integral part of 360 degrees ie. 360/2 , 360/3, 360/4, 360/5... etc.

Apply that operation to any shape once and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to repeat the transform and create a new copy. Repeat until you have a full circle.

Here's one shape and a full circle of 22,5 degrees a step rotated copies:

[image]

A clever design of the original shape helps to have more interesting patterns. Combining different shapes, rotation angles and colorings and applying also Transform > Scale and  > Reflect are other tools to achieve continuity and variation at the same time.

It's a good idea to do as the commentators have written: See tutorials and check how some traditional designs are constructed.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers.
I googled mandala tutorials like @Billy Kerr said. Thank you for that.

While searching I came up to a tutorial that uses polar grid tool to create mandalas and tried to use it for simpler shapes.

1-Use polar grid tool to draw a circle. Click the circle then 'divide' in 'pathfinder'.
[image: Polar grid]

2-Ungroup the object, then erase the circle leaving one slice.

[image: One slice of the circle]

3-Group the slice then drag to symbols, export type: graphic

[image]

4-Mirror the slice and paste it until you get the circle back.

[image]

5-Select one slice and isolate it. Anything you draw inside that slice will be multiplied on the other slices when you exit isolation mode.

[image]

6-Now, exit the isolation mode and it will look like this.

[image]

7-Select the slice again and delete the line of the polar grid.

[image]

And that's it. I think this is one of possible ways to draw such shapes.
Thank you all for your help.